# Append dynamic created table with div?

Tags: jquery

Please see the below mention code in which I tried to create a dynamic table and append row in it then i append table in div but its not working somehow, can anybody please help ?

```
var procount[];
var b=1
var tables = '<table id="table' + procount[b] + '"></table>'
//  var tbody = $('#table'+procount[b]+'').children('tbody');
//Then if no tbody just select your table
//   var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#table' + procount[b] + '');
$('table#table' + procount[b] + '').append('<tr align="center"><th style="text-align: center;" >No Schedule Found.</th>  </tr>');
//below is to append with div
 $('#provider' + procount[b] + '').append(tables);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually created a table. Here how it should be done:

```
var procount = [1,2];
var b=1

var tables = $("<table>", {id: "table" + procount[b]})
                 .appendTo($('#provider' + procount[b]));
var $tr = $("<tr>", {align: "center"}).appendTo(tables);
var $td = $("<td>", {style: "text-align: center;", text: "No Schedule Found."});
$tr.append($td)>;
```